# Run last set Task in time interval

Tags: java, java-threads

The headline is probably a bit off, so here's the expanded question:

I have an user control, for example a `Button`. Whenever I click the button, an *expensive* `Runnable` should be scheduled in an `ScheduledExecutorService`. Because the `Runnable` runs some *expensive* code, I had the idea to only run the said `Runnable` if the button was **not** pressed another time during a given time interval. If the button was pressed again within the said interval, the timer should be reset and the same `Runnable` should be running after a given delay. If the button has not been pressed another time during the delay interval, the `Runnable` is executed.

Is there some build-in way or can I realize this somehow?

The current implementation looks like this:

```
public class RepeatedCallScheduler {

    private long waitForMillis;

    private long systemTimeMillis;

    public RepeatedCallScheduler(long waitForMillis) {
        this.waitForMillis = waitForMillis;
    }

    public void run(Runnable runnable) {
        this.systemTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Run logic
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RepeatedCallScheduler scheduler = new RepeatedCallScheduler(500);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            scheduler.run(() -> doSomething());
        });
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

**Example**:

In this example, the time delay values 500 milliseconds, meaning 500 milliseconds after the last click on the button the method `doSomething()` should run.

I click the button on time (in milliseconds) `x` and the second time I click it at time `x + 300`. Now the first click event should not run but at time `x + 800` the scheduler should run the method `doSomething()` asynchronously, as long as the button is not clicked again during `x + 300` and `x + 800`.

After this the program prints "hello" *once*, not twice.

As I asked before, is there a way to properly implement this with the use of a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private long waitForMillis;

private AtomicInteger taskNo;

private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

public RepeatedCallScheduler(long waitForMillis) {
    this.waitForMillis = waitForMillis;
    this.taskNo = new AtomicInteger();
    executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4); // Whatever you need
}

public void run(Runnable runnable) {

    int no = taskNo.incrementAndGet();

        executorService.schedule(() -> {
            // Check if the task should be executed
            if (no == taskNo.get()) {
                // Logic.. 
            }
        }, waitForMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You could wrap the code to be executed with a container and give it an id. If the global id changed, a new task came in before execution and it should not be started.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Can you please explain what the `AtomicInteger` is here for? I didn't quite get that part. The code is working perfectly!

Comment: As the `RepeatedCallScheduler` may be accessed by different threads, the `taskNo` acts as the global id store, telling the scheduler which tasks to execute and which to skip. It should be an `AtomicInteger` to make it thread-safe meaning every call will get a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you schedule some action you receive `ScheduledFuture` instance which you can use to `cancel` previous task and schedule new one:

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> task;

button.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (task != null) {
        // change this to true if you want to cancel already running task
        task.cancel(false);
    }
    task = scheduler.schedule(() -> doSomething(), 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
});
```

Comment: Didn't thought about using it that way. Even though it is working absolutely fine, just as the answer below yours, I will mark the one below as accepted since it's closer to my current implementation. Thanks for your help!